# How to add swf file in vaadin

Tags: flash, vaadin

I want to add swf file created by pdf2swf in vaadin window,

So I tried with code given in Book of Vaadin https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.embedded.html

`final ClassResource flashResource = new ClassResource("Requirements.swf", getMainWindow().getApplication());

final Embedded embedded = new Embedded("Embedded Caption", flashResource);

embedded.setType(Embedded.TYPE_OBJECT);

embedded.setMimeType("application/x-shockwave-flash");

embedded.setWidth("100px");

embedded.setHeight("100px");

mainWindow.addComponent(embedded);

mainWindow.requestRepaintAll();`

But still I cant see the swf in vaadin window.

Thanks,
Yogesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine the problem here is the  location of the SWF in your web application; in this code, you are using a ClassResource - this means  "Requirements.swf" needs to be in the root of the **classpath** of the web application.

Typically, the easiest place to put this for a quick test is WEB-INF/classes.

See https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.resources.html for the different resource classes, and where to place those resources.

Note that putting the file in the root of the webapplication is not *quite* as easy as you imagine, as you'll have to change the default servlet mapping configuration.